# how to retrieve input data from a two column form into a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

heres my code that I am trying to use to get the input data.

```
$itemList = array();
$itemList= $_POST['itemList'];
$itemArray = array(array('itemName' => $itemList[0],'itemQuantity' =>  $itemList[1]));

foreach ($itemArray as $item => $innerItem) {
    foreach ($innerItem as $value) {
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

here is my form (its a dynamic form so user can add new rows)

```
<form class="col s12" action="" method="POST">
     <div class="center-align">
       <button type="button" name="button" class="waves-effect #ff3d00 deep-orange accent-3 waves-red btn-large addField">Add a new row</button>
     </div>
     <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center-align" data-field="name">Item Name</th>
                <th class="center-align" data-field="price">Item Quantity</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="listWrapper">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input type="text" class="validate" name="itemList[]">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input  type="text" class="validate" name="itemList[]">
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input type="text" class="validate" name="itemList[]">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input  type="text" class="validate" name="itemList[]">
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
<input type="submit" class="btn #ff3d00 deep-orange accent-3 center-align" name="sendList" value="SEND">
</form>
```

when I run the code with say name-apple qty=2 and name-cherries and qty=3
I get just apples2 printed out.

what I want is something like this:

```
array(
    array( [itemName]=>'apples'[itemQuantity]=>2),
    array( [itemName]=>'cherries'[itemQuantity]=>3)
)
```

Comment: If you didn't want keys, there's [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). Something like: `$itemArray = array_chunk($itemList, 2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php

$itemList = $_POST['itemlist']

// Assume $itemlist is
$itemList = array('Apples',2,'Cherries',3,'Bananas',4,'Mango',5);

$itemArray = array();

$howMany = count($itemList) / 2;

for ($i=0; $i<$howMany; $i++) {

$itemArray[] = array('itemname' => $itemList[$i*2], 'itemQuantity' => $itemList[$i*2+1]);

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($itemArray);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemname] => Apples
            [itemQuantity] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemname] => Cherries
            [itemQuantity] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [itemname] => Bananas
            [itemQuantity] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [itemname] => Mango
            [itemQuantity] => 5
        )

)
```

I should have just looped with $i+2, instead of all the division, etc. You should check that your $itemList has an even number of elements though.

Comment: thanks very much. i will try using the $i+2 tho. but what does the [$i*2] and [$i*2+1] please?

Comment: @dela The [$i*2] and [$i*2+1] are the indexes into the $itemList array, (0,1; 2,3; 3,4...)

Comment: oh yeah that i know.. I just wanted to know exactly it works. since my php is just intermediate. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a multi-dimensional array, do like this:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sandbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" >
            <input type="text" name="itemList[0][itemName]" value="apples" />
            <input type="text" name="itemList[0][itemQuantity]" value="2" />
            <input type="text" name="itemList[1][itemName]" value="cherries" />
            <input type="text" name="itemList[1][itemQuantity]" value="3" />

            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <pre><?php var_dump($_POST['itemList']); ?></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should be:

```php
array(2) {
    [1] => array(2) {
        ['itemName'] => string(6) "apples"
        ['itemQuantity'] => string(1) "2"
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
        ['itemName'] => string(8) "cherries"
        ['itemQuantity'] => string(1) "3"
    }
}
```